# visual paradigm two databases in same project

Tags: visual-paradigm

How can I have two databases in the same project in Visual Paradigm 10?
Right now I created two **Entity Relationship Diagrams** One for each database.

The problem is when I go to **Tools > Database > Generate** I can only select one specific database and both diagrams get applied to it.

I want each file to apply to it's own database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Paradigm can define multiple databases for the project (one for each DBMS), but any instance it will only pick one (the default one) for code/DDL generation. Within a project all models should be on the same database. I suggest you can send in your request to Visual Paradigm's support team (support@visual-paradigm.com) to discuss in details about your usage, and see how they can help.